# Can BIRT use the output of one query as the input for another query

Tags: birt

I have a report that needs to be generated from two different queries.

- The first query retrieves a list of information from one data source
- The second query must then be called once for each of the records returned by the first query?
- Each result set from the second query will then be displayed in separate report tables.

Any pointers are welcome.

**It is not possible to perform a SQL join on the first and second query.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible lets assume you have bind your first query results to data table. you can create another table inside the parent table cell and assign your 2 data set to that table  with filter of dataset 1

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rmc/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/birt-13-1.html

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rmc/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/birt-13-2.html

Answer (score 1):

The functionality I require is provided by SubReports

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/examples/reports/birt2.1/subreport/index.php